# Will the voter get money if its voted node becomes the proposer

Tags: consensus

In EOS, will the voter get money if its voted node becomes the proposer?

Also, how is the proposer itself rewarded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming by node you mean block producer.  If the block producer agrees to pay the voters a share of the block rewards, then yes, a voter will get money.  However, it's been my experience in the EOS community that this is frowned upon, as most community members suggest the block producers with the best tech to support the block chain should be voted in, not those incentivizing via a share of the rewards.

A block producer is reward via block rewards, similar to Ethereum and Bitcoin.

Comment: The vast amount of voters should be rewarded right? Otherwise what's the incentive of taking part into the EOS network?

Comment: If you mean what’s the incentive to vote, the incentive is to have the best possible network available for use.  Taken to an extreme, let’s say I announce my BP candidacy but I have no way of connecting to the EOSIO network and producing blocks, however, I’m willing to give 100% of my rewards to the voters.  The network would become very unstable and every time it was my turn to produce a block no one would be able to transact on the network.  Now assume everyone did this and got voted in.  See the problem?

Comment: I’m not a BP but I believe part of their rewards also go to community projects.  So in a way the rewards are going back to token holders indirectly and a vote for a BP is a vote for the community projects that BP feels are important.